# Libgdx and Box2D Draw a custom shape

Tags: box2d, libgdx

I have the following shape: http://s16.postimg.org/sfhb5wgdx/slime.png and I want to draw it in LibGDx just like that because am using Box2d wand will be used in collisions. I have heard I can used a mesh to create this but there isn't much documentation about drawing anything from an image. Do I seriously have to define all the points myself? Is there a better way to extract a shape from in image?

Comment: you should probably accept the answer if the solution worked for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Physics body editor
https://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/   this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you! Thats what I have been looking for!

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac OSX Mavericks because this application doesn't support Java 7..

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns then install java 6 on Mac OSX Mavericks. I'm currnetly running all java6, java7 both on my mac with default set to java6. you can use http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572 to install java 6.